# How Java BigInteger nextProbablePrime method works?

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm working with Java `BigInteger` Class and curious about the Algorithm behind `nextProbablePrime` method. I know about some efficient primality testing algorithm like `Miller-Rabin` but not sure about which algorithm was implemented here.

Trying the following code for a good time and still no response.

```
BigInteger number = BigInteger.ZERO;
number = number.setBit(82589933);
number = number.nextProbablePrime();
```

Comment: Have you read the code? Java is open source.

Comment: How to get the code?

Comment: @ManojBanik Most IDEs have an option to see the source. You can also google to find out.

Comment: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: I got it here as well: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java

Comment: You'll want a sieve to cheaply remove most non-primes. For number of this size finding a prime is almost too hard. They are about log(N) apart which at this size is millions of composites between each prime. That's a lot of testing of enormous numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone through with [the source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java) of [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html). It is internally using the [*MillerRabin* algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) for the [`nextProbablePrime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#nextProbablePrime()) method.

Comment: How about the increment, when the test failed? Is it linear?

Comment: It is written as a linear approach after checking the bitLength() > 6 so the number is composite looping continue. If bitLength() < 4 then it is prime otherwise it was checking with the help of Miller Rabin algorithm.

`code`
* n-1 = m * (Math.pow(a, k))
* T = Math.pow(a, m) mod n
* for p=1 to k-1
   T = Math.pow(T, 2) mod n
   if answer is not -1 or 1 then T - n 
   if final answer is -1 then prime otherwise composite
end for
`code`

Comment: It increments by 1, as I found this code: "BigInteger result = this.add(ONE);" So, I can improve this part when I start from an odd number and then incrementing by two.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incomplete. As can be seen in the source code, if the size of the prime is >= 100 bits then it uses *both* Miller-Rabin and Lucas-Lehmer tests.

Answer (score 1):

Why your example runs and runs without returning:

Your number is 82million *bits* long, and (by prime number th'm) such primes are ab out 82million / log_e(2) numbers apart.  So you're asking Miller-Rabin to test about 15million-ish candidates, where each candidate involves 82million bits, and each check is non-trivial.  So yeah, even efficient algorithms like Miller-Rabin will take a while on such beyond-mind-bogglingly-big inputs.

(I remember once running raising one number to another, having it take too long, and complaining to the language-developer that they should use repeated squaring for faster exponentiation ... before I stepped back and realized that my test-number also had millions of digits.)